# PHP iMagick Load image from another imagick object rather than file

Tags: php, image, load, imagick

I have created two imagick objects `$obj_one` add `$obj_two` and loaded image from file **test.pdf** into `$obj_one`.

Now i need to load image from `$obj_one` into `$obj_two` pretty much the same as from the file, but from another imagick object.

How can i do it?

Note i set `$obj_two` resolution twice as much than `$obj_one` and i need image to resize upon loading to `$obj_one`.

**EDIT**:

```
$obj_one = new Imagick();
$obj_two = new Imagick();

$obj_one->setOption('pdf:use-cropbox', 'true');
$obj_one->readImage("docs/test.pdf");


$output_x_res = 800; //px
$output_y_res = $obj_one->getImageHeight() * $output_x_res / $obj_one->getImageWidth();

$Img_Dpi_Arr = $obj_one->getImageResolution();

$final_x_dpi = ceil(($Img_Dpi_Arr['x'] / $obj_one->getImageWidth()) * $output_x_res);
$final_y_dpi = ceil(($Img_Dpi_Arr['y'] / $obj_one->getImageHeight()) * $output_y_res);

$obj_two->setResolution($final_x_dpi,$final_y_dpi);

...
```

Comment: Wait, you said you're using `image.jpg`.  I thought you said you were using vector graphics?  Which is it?

Comment: Ok i edited question, i just tried simplify it at first.

Comment: Could you just do something like `$obj2 = new obj1` or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @shakabra, He actually wants to re-render the original PDF (vector graphics and all), but in a different variable without reading the file again.

Comment: $Bard correct hopefully it wont use as much resorces guess i could just save into BLOB variable and then read it, but i bet there's better way

Comment: Never mind when i use GetImageBlob() and ReadImageBlob() it does not resize as if i use ReadImage() so its pointless i have to write image file first and then read file to resize its only solution i found